# How do I call WriteObject() of Cmdlet class to output objects with different types?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Right now I'm calling `WriteObject(identities1, enumerateCollection:true)` first and then `WriteObject(identities2, enumerateCollection:true)`.

If `identities1` and `identities2` are the same type, the output looks okay. But if they are different types, the output for `identities2` is blank.

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This is quirk of how the PowerShell formatting (F&O) engine works.  I've argued (apparently unsuccessfully) that this is a bug.  You should find that the output is there if you use Format-List.  Where I've seen this problem is that the first set of objects uses table formatting (either configured by a format ps1xml file or has <= 4 properties).  Then the different object type has > 4 properties.  PowerShell can't format the objects in tabular format so it just punts completely.  I haven't tried this, but if you create a format ps1xml1 file for your output types, you could try to force both types to use list formatting.